# How to load differentiate DLL's using a hash code C#

Tags: c#, dll, hash

Inside folder I have the file "module.dll". The project "A" use the "module.dll" like a dependency. The correct way to work is "module.dll" stay into same folder of the project ok? Ok.

If I change the code of "module.dll" and don't want to replace the original file, what I do?

I imagine create a hash code of the "module.dll" and change the file name.
I.E.:

```
version 1.0
hash: ABCD123
original file name: module.dll
new file name: ABCD123_module.dll

version 2.0
hash: ABCD456
original file name: module.dll
new file name: ABCD456_module.dll

etc...
```

Knowing that, the project "A" need save the hash of "module.dll" and when call the reference join the hash with dll name ("ABCD456_module.dll") to load the correct file.

How I can do this?

Thanks

Comment: You can handle the `AssemblyResolve` event of AppDomain to load the correct module at runtime.

Comment: @P.Kouvarakis In my project I can't use an AppDomain

Comment: @jsfelipearaujo Why not? Is it a .NET Core project? Also, can you modifiy the app.config or web.config file?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain my boss don't like AppDomain =/ . Yeah, I can modify these files

Comment: AppDomain is by far the easiest way to do it...What does your boss have against it?

Comment: @Ilovemymonkey I don't know. He said "AppDomain is to easy, find another way". I have no way out.

Comment: I would be suspicious of any boss that thinks a solution is "too easy", Is it actually a teacher and you can't use AppDomain for this assignment?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I don't know the real reason to don't use an AppDomain, I think he wants other way to solve this problem

Comment: Personally, I think as a developer you should be asking why not...It does seem to me like he's a teacher and not a boss...

Comment: To make it simple. You can write a loader, use the loader to get the real dll path, set the environment PATH in the loader, then use the loader to start the real exe.